# Android Google Fused Location Api gives null latitude and longitude to get a address

Tags: android, api, location

I am implementing a Fused Location Api, to get a device latitude and longitude as well its address. I am trying to run my app on my personal device, i.e. it is 4.3 then the latitude and longitude is not coming. but when I installed the same app on android kitkat and android lollipop,It is working well.

In Android 4.3, I enabled the wi-fi and GPS Both, But it is displaying a null Location when i debug the same app code with android 4.3. I know, there are some device issues.

Can you people help me. It already take a huge number of days. so please

Comment: can you please post your code here

Comment: yes sure....please see my qustion again within 5min.

Comment: please see in below answer. it is my source code.

Comment: does google maps work on the device which does not give you  latitude and longitude

Comment: only map is showing no curent location found.... i need only latitude and longitude in my App. no map required

Comment: I meant the "google maps" app. if you open google maps app, does the map show your current location?

Comment: No, please tell me whats the reason behind it?

Comment: looks like your GPS receiver has some issues..

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest try installing this app and see if it can detect GPS

Comment: Even When I install a food panda app in my device no location i have found.always it gives a message like , we could not locate you. kindly mannually search the location.

Comment: which device are u using? Looks like a hardware issue.

Comment: ok i am trying and will update you.

Comment: Iam using sony xepri m 4.3 version

Comment: What kind of hardware issues?

Comment: no application giving me my location. what should i do. can u plz suggest me.

Comment: Try to do a factory reset or take your device to a service centre

Comment: Rakesh I have do factory Reset But no Solution FOund. Even the normal Google Maps App working. But Android Not.